# Hibernate, Getting an error when using createNativeQuery method

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am trying to execute a query in hibernate I am using StringBuffer for my query. I get an error on `createNativeQuery(...)`. When I hover over the method it says

> The method createNativeQuery(String, Class) in the type EntityManager is not applicable for the arguments (StringBuffer, Class).

I have tried to change the method to `createNamedQuery(..)` and `createQuery(..)` but it does not work. Any suggestions? Below is my code

```
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    logger.info("In getTrafficProfileByCosClass2Allocations className :- " +  cosClassAllocation );
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryByCos2Allocation, TrafficProfile.class);
    query.setParameter(1, direction);
    query.setParameter(2, cosClassAllocation.getCos1());
    query.setParameter(3, cosClassAllocation.getCos2());
    return  (TrafficProfile) query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `createNativeQuery` method needs a `String` as the first argument, which can be easily created from a `StringBuffer`.

Assuming `queryByCos2Allocation` is a `StringBuffer`, change this:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryByCos2Allocation, TrafficProfile.class);
```

To this:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryByCos2Allocation.toString(), TrafficProfile.class);
```